# How to correctly parse a tiled map in a text file?

Tags: python, maps, pygame, tile

I'm making a RPG with Python and `pygame` for a school project. In order to create the few maps, I have chosen the Tile Mapping techniques I have seen in some tutorials, using a `*.txt` file.

However, I have to cut some sprites (trees, houses, ...) into several pieces. The problem is that I'm running out of characters to represent them all!

I also remember that it's possible to take several characters as one (ex : take `"100"` as one an not as one `"1"` and two `"0"`s) and/or to put spaces between characters in the file (e.g. `"170 0 2 5 12 48"` which is read as six sprites).

But I really don't know how to adapt my program to do this way. I'm pretty sure that I need to modify the way the file is read, but how?

Here's the reading function :

```
class Niveau:
    def __init__(self, fichier):
        self.fichier = fichier
        self.structure = 0

    def generer(self):
        """MÃ©thode permettant de gÃ©nÃ©rer le niveau en fonction du fichier.
        On crÃ©e une liste gÃ©nÃ©rale, contenant une liste par ligne Ã  afficher"""     
        #On ouvre le fichier
        with open(self.fichier, "r") as fichier:
            structure_niveau = []
            #On parcourt les lignes du fichier
            for ligne in fichier:
                ligne_niveau = []
                #On parcourt les sprites (lettres) contenus dans le fichier
                for sprite in ligne:
                    #On ignore les "\n" de fin de ligne
                    if sprite != '\n':
                        #On ajoute le sprite Ã  la liste de la ligne
                        ligne_niveau.append(sprite)
                #On ajoute la ligne Ã  la liste du niveau
                structure_niveau.append(ligne_niveau)
            #On sauvegarde cette structure
            self.structure = structure_niveau

    def afficher(self, fenetre):
        """MÃ©thode permettant d'afficher le niveau en fonction 
        de la liste de structure renvoyÃ©e par generer()"""
        #Chargement des images (seule celle d'arrivÃ©e contient de la transparence)
        Rocher = pygame.image.load(image_Rocher).convert()
        Buisson = pygame.image.load(image_Buisson).convert()

        #On parcourt la liste du niveau
        num_ligne = 0
        for ligne in self.structure:
            #On parcourt les listes de lignes
            num_case = 0
            for sprite in ligne:
                #On calcule la position rÃ©elle en pixels
                x = (num_case+0.5) * taille_sprite
                y = (num_ligne+1) * taille_sprite
                if sprite == 'R':                  #R = Rocher
                    fenetre.blit(Rocher, (x,y))
                if sprite == 'B':
                    fenetre.blit(Buisson,(x,y))

                num_case += 1
            num_ligne += 1
```

Comment: So currently your file looks like `1a13b` and you'd like it to be `1 a 1 3 b` instead, to support e.g. `1 a 1 3 b 22 a6`?

Comment: That's it. I was thinking of using a character which wouldn't be readed (ex : 1** a** 1** 3** b** 22* a6*) but the space is still a problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
for ligne in fichier:
    ligne_niveau = []
    #On parcourt les sprites (lettres) contenus dans le fichier
    for sprite in ligne.split(): # note split here
        ligne_niveau.append(sprite) # no need to check for line end
    #On ajoute la ligne Ã  la liste du niveau
    structure_niveau.append(ligne_niveau)
```

`split` without any arguments will join all consecutive whitespace (including tabs `'\t'` and newlines `'\n'`) into a single split. For example:

```
"\ta 13 b \t22     6e\n".split() == ['a', '13', 'b', '22', '6e']
```

Note that the "sprites" don't have to be the same length, so there's no need for fill characters like extra `0`s or `*`s. You can also simplify using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def generer(self):
    with open(self.fichier) as fichier:
        self.structure = [ligne.split() for ligne in fichier]
```

Alternatively, consider using a comma-separated value format - Python has a [whole module (`csv`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for that:

```
a,13,b,22,6e
```